# Why does r-value reference to object generator call require copy constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm getting trouble with the following code with Visual Studio 2010 C++.

makeA() is just an object generator idiom in C++ (like std::make_pair)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A{ // 7th line
    A() {}
    A(A &&) {printf("move\n");}
    ~A() {printf("~A();\n");}
private:
    A(const A &) {printf("copy\n");} // 12th line
};

A makeA()
{
    return A();
}

int main()
{
    A &&rrefA(makeA()); // 22nd line
    return 0;
}
```

Error message

```
2>d:\test.cpp(22): error C2248: 'A::A' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'
2>          d:\test.cpp(12) : see declaration of 'A::A'
2>          d:\test.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'A'
2>
```

I expect makeA() to call both A() constructor and A(A &&) constructor, and 22nd line to call makeA() and nothing else. (If without RVO)
The compiler should not require A(const A &) constructor to be accessible, am I right?

Can you tell me what's wrong with the code?

With recent version of g++, 'g++ -std=c++0x' and 'g++ -std=c++0x -fno-elide-constructors' compiles the code without any error.

Comment: Try changing `A()` to `{}` - it might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935639/can-we-return-objects-having-a-deleted-private-copy-move-constructor-by-value-fr

Comment: @Pubby Good link, but I think that's somehow different issue. Leaving `A makeA();' only in the code and moving the body of makeA() to the other file should make the mentioned change invisible. Without the 22nd line, the code compiles. I think it's not the problem of makeA() function.

Comment: 99% sure this is a compiler bug. Please post a bug report on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) and post a link to it here.

Comment: This bug is fixed in VS2012 RC. Time to move onto VS2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in the optimizer. The compiler attempts to ellide the move, but is only programmed to ellide a copy constructor- which requires a copy constructor to exist to be ellided in the first place.

I don't recall what (if any) the fix for this error is, but it might have been fixed in SP1.

Comment: Not fixed in VC++ 2010 SP1. Maybe in VC11?

Comment: I've installed VS 2012 RC and checked the code working. It's fixed in VS2012. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, it works if the copy constructor is not defined, I think, but still publicly accessible.

Comment: Maybe publicly accessible default copy constructor was considered to be calling.