# c++ {*this} inside curly braces

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code compiles fine:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors && ./a.out
```

However, if I remove the curly braces from `{*this}` and use `*this` instead, I will face with error:

> error: use of deleted function ‘Obj::Position::Position(Obj::Position&&)’

What is the difference between `{*this}` and `*this`?

```
class Obj
{
    template<bool> friend class Position;

    double data;
public:
    class Position
    {
        const Obj& ref;
    public:
        inline Position(const Obj& ref): ref(ref){}
        inline Position(Position const &) = delete;
        inline Position(Position &&) = delete;
    };
    inline Obj(){}
    inline Obj(const double &data): data(data){}
    inline auto get_pos() const-> Position{return {*this};} /* <--- here */
    inline auto get_pos()-> Position{return {*this};}
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference between the two is really quite subtle. C++11 introduced the feature *list initialization* (also sometimes called *brace initialization*):

Before C++11, when you want to default-construct and object `o` of type `Obj` and construct a `Position p` from `o`, you had to write

```
Obj o;              // default construct o
Obj::Position p(o); // construct p using Position(Obj const&)
```

A common error for beginners (especially with a Java background) was to try to write this:

```
Obj o();            // mistake: declares a function o returning an Obj
Obj::Position p(o); // error: no constructor takes a function
```

The first line declares a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034606/is-there-any-use-for-local-function-declarations), and the second one tries to create a `Position` using a constructor that takes a function pointer as its argument. In order to have a uniform initializer syntax, C++11 introduced list initialization:

```
Obj oo{};             // new in C++11: default construct o of type Obj
Obj::Position p1(oo); // possible before (and after) C++11
Obj::Position p2{oo}; // new in C++11: construct p2 using Position(Obj const&)
```

This new syntax also works in `return`-statements, and this leads to the answer of your question: the difference between `return {*this};` and `return *this;` is that the former initializes the return value **directly** from `*this`, whereas the latter first converts `*this` to a temporary `Position` object and then initializes the return value indirectly **from this temporary**, which fails because both the copy- and move-constructor have been explicitly deleted.

As the previous posters have noted, most compilers elide these temporary objects because they aren't really useful for anything; but this is only possible if they could be used in theory because either a copy or a move constructor is available. Because this leads to a lot of confusion (why do I need braces around my return statement? is the compiler going to elide the copy or not?), C++17 does away with these unnecessary temporaries, and initializes the return value **directly** in both cases (`return {*this};` and `return *this`).

You can try this using a compiler that supports C++17. In clang 4.0 or gcc 7.1, you can pass `--std=c++1z`, and your code should compile fine with and without braces.

Answer (score 38):

When the curly braces are present, you're [*copy-list-initializing*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#copy-list-initialization) the return value, no copy/move constructor is involved. The [return value is constructed in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15328382/241631) using the `Position(const Obj&)` constructor.

Note that the code would fail to compile even with the curly braces if you made the `Position(const Obj&)` constructor `explicit` because *copy-list-initialization* does not allow explicit constructors to be called.

If you omit the curly braces, then semantically a temporary `Position` object is constructed within the function, and the return value is move constructed from that temporary. In practice, most implementations will elide the move construction, but it still requires a viable move constructor to be present, which is not the case here because it has been explicitly deleted. This is the reason your code will not compile without braces.

Using a C++17 compiler, your code will compile even without the curly braces because of [guaranteed copy-elision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/241631).

Comment: I wonder why I see `Position(Obj::Position&&)’` in the error rather than `Position(Obj::Position&)’` when I omit braces. It looks like opposite.

Comment: @ar2015 Did you mean why do you see `Position(Position&&)` instead of `Position(Position const&)` in the error message? It's because you have a prvalue `Position` object from which to initialize the return value and the move constructor is a better match. If you comment out the `inline Position(Position &&) = delete;` line, the error message will contain the copy constructor.

Comment: it basically a case of  "I prohibited it, then I tried to do that" If that's actually required

Answer (score 14):

This is a good one! This is because `return {...}` means "return an object of the function's return type initialized with list initializer ...".

List initializers are described in more details here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list%20initialization

So, the difference is that `{*this}` calls this:

```
inline Position(const Obj& ref): ref(ref){}
```

Whereas `*this` tries converting `Obj&` to `Position` by using explicitly deleted assignment operators (pre C++11, they would have to be made `private`, and you'd get an even more confusing error message if list initializers would be available...):

```
inline Position(Position const &) = delete;
inline Position(Position &&) = delete;
```

Answer (score -2):

frankly, using your class and the following main():

```
int main()
{
    Obj o1;
    cout<<"get position"<<'\n';
    Obj::Position pos= o1.get_pos();


    cout.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

it does not compile (gcc/mingw) in both cases(-std=c++14), with or without curly braces and it complains about missing Position(Position&&) constructor, which is deleted. It is reasonable because it seems that in both cases a construction of the temporary return object is performed, which then it is to be moved to the destination. Which is impossible as move constructor is deleted.
Conversely, using -std=c++17 flag it compiles in both cases (with or without curly braces) as, most probably, we are hitting the guaranteed return-value optimization of c++17.
Hope this helps.