# Constructing class with member tuple containing rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11

When trying to construct a class which is supposed to hold a tuple created by calling `std::forward_as_tuple` I ran into the following error when compiling with clang(187537) and libc++:

```
/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:329:11: error: rvalue reference to type 'int' cannot
      bind to lvalue of type 'int'
        : value(__t.get())
          ^     ~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:447:8: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__tuple_leaf<0, int &&, false>::__tuple_leaf' requested here
struct __tuple_impl<__tuple_indices<_Indx...>, _Tp...>
       ^
tuple.cpp:31:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'make_foo2<int>' requested here
    make_foo2(1 + 1);
    ^
In file included from tuple.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:330:10: error: static_assert failed "Can not copy a
      tuple with rvalue reference member"
        {static_assert(!is_rvalue_reference<_Hp>::value, "Can not copy ...
```

I was able to work around the above error by declaring the return type differently, but, from my understanding, it should have the same semantics so I would not expect it to stop the error.  In the below code `make_foo` is the workaround which does not error out and make_foo2 causes the above error.  I am able to successfully compile both versions using gcc 4.8.1 and the version of clang at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e16df45f99b727ce911f82d92cf57f63-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336).

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template<class Tuple>
struct foo
{
    Tuple t;
    foo(Tuple &&t) : t(std::move(t)) { }
};

template<class... Args>
using ForwardedTuple = decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args>())...));

template<class... Args>
foo<ForwardedTuple<Args...>> make_foo(Args&&... args)
{
    return {std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
}

template<class... Args>
auto make_foo2(Args&& ...args) ->
    decltype(foo<decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
{
    return foo<decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main()
{
    make_foo(1 + 1);

    make_foo2(1 + 1);
}
```

What is the difference between the above `make_foo` functions and is `make_foo2` incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: `std::forward_as_tuple` creates a tupel of `rvalue` references (or `lvalue` references). Is that what you want?

Comment: @Walter - I believe so; I'm interested in manipulating the values of the resulting tuple in the same expression it was created in so, from my understanding, the rvalue's captured in the tuple should exist  for the whole expression. (ie. `cout << std::get<0>(make_foo(1 + 1).t) << endl;`

Comment: So both `make_foo` and `make_foo2` compile at coliru's clang++ and g++ but `make_foo2` does not compile on your own clang++ with libc++?

Comment: One difference between `make_foo` and `make_foo2` is that `make_foo` doesn't require `foo<...>` to have either a copy or move ctor (none is required). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7938941/420683) and the comments to it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you return foo<> from make_foo2. But foo doesn't have move constructor generated (Compiler won't generate it). Therefore copy constructor is called and compilation fails because of that.

Comment: Thanks.  When I add `foo(foo&&) = default; foo& operator=(foo&&) & = default;` to foo it then compiles `make_foo2`.  Would you mind going into a little detail on why the compiler was unable to generate the move constructor for `foo`?  I thought that since the tuple member was movable, and no copy, move, or destructor was declared that the compiler should generate the move constructor.

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure. Looks to me it should have been generated according to C++11 rules. It might just be compiler issue. Not sure about Clang (that version you're using) but one of C++11 features Visual Studio compiler is (at least was) missing is generating default move constructors.

Comment: It works fine as is with gcc in ideone.com: http://ideone.com/pQ3jzt so it does look like it's a compiler issue.