# Is it possible to construct only const objects of specific type in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, constants

I want to implement the class with the following properties:

```
class A { ... };

const A a;  // ok - should work.
A b;        // compilation error - shouldn't work!
```

Also, it would be better, if the `const`ness of an object depends on the constructors signature:

```
const A c(1);  // ok - should work.
A d("a");      // ok - should work.
A e(2);        // compilation error - shouldn't work!
```

Usage of C++11 is allowed, if required.

---

#### Update #1

Since I don't know the answer, it's not required to strictly follow the code above - any C++ pattern providing similar semantics is welcome.

Comment: You can't, but you can make all member functions `const`

Comment: I recall thinking it would be useful to have a `const` constructor for this purpose, though I can no longer recall my use-case.  Something to do with copying vs not-copying some internal data.

Comment: I don't really see how it's any of the class's business, to be honest. You can make member functions and member data `const` and that should be sufficient for all needs.

Comment: @OP I don't know of any way to do this offhand, but can you explain the difference between what you're asking and a non-const instance of an immutable class (all methods are const, no non-const, non-private data).

Comment: If you make the type `A` private and disallow both copying and moving, you can only bind references to it. Then, you can provide `make_A` functions that return const- and non-const `A`s based on the parameter types. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b9296193b20bc90) (Explicit copying and explicit moving can allowed through other `make_A` overloads.)

Comment: @dyp I don't believe it's legal to return by value if the copy constructor is private, even if you're binding to a reference.

Comment: @MarkB I'm using a braced-init-list to return, this directly calls the ctor of the return value (no copy nor move involved). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7935639/420683

Answer (score 5):

1.You can create class with only const methods and private members.

2.You can create "normal" class but declare its constructor as private. Then you will need a friend-class with following method (or something similar)

```
class ConstClassProvider{
public:
    static const A* getA(/* you can have params here*/)
    {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

so

```
A a1;//error
const A a2;//error
A *a3 = ConstClassProvider::getA(); //error
const A *a4 = ConstClassProvider::getA(); //ok!
```

Comment: Thanks. I have typed without IDE or compiler.

Comment: Ouch... **Please DO NOT return a raw pointer with implied ownership;** use a `unique_ptr` instead!

Comment: It is just a simple sample.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make an immutable class. In other words use encapsulation to prevent users of your class from setting any fields.

Basically:

```
class Immutable{
private:
  const int intField;
  const std::string textField;
public:
  Immutable(const std::string& ref, int copy) : intField{copy}, testField{ref} {}
  int getIntField(){return intField;}
  const std::string& getTextField(){ return textField; }
}
```

Then just don't expose your internals via setters.

Comment: Yes, but is independent of signature.

Comment: @user2672165 - I don;t understand your objection. Can you expand?

Comment: Unclear sorry. I mean this class will always be const regardless of constructor signature.

Comment: It could work pretty easily at runtime based on an injected policy of some kind but not at compile time (as far as I can figure). An alternative would be to have two internal classes that expose different sets of functions that can be performed on the outer class members but that would be conceptually the same as two derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with an extra constructor argument which is a reference to self, e.g.:

```
class X {
public:
    X(X const& self) {
        assert(this == &self);
    }

private:
    X(X&);
};
```

And then invoke it like so:

```
X const x(x); // works
X y(y); // fails to compile
X z(x); // fails at run-time
```

Comment: @stefan Why not? It is as defined as `this` is.

Comment: The pointer is defined, but the object is not yet initialized... However, the fact that you need an assert() limits the feat to a runtime check instead of a compile time check (the OP is asking for a compile time check.) That being said with a couple of templates you may be able to replace your assert with a compile time check.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is you are looking for:

```
class AData {
public:
    AData() : intValue( 0 ), stringValue( 0 ) {}
    void SetInt( int arg ) { intValue = arg; }
    void SetString( const char* arg ) { stringValue = arg; }

private:
    int intValue;
    const char* stringValue;
};

class A {
public:
    A();
    void Init( int intValue ) const;
    void Init( const char* stringValue );

private:
    AData* p;
};

A::A() : p( new AData )
{
}

void A::Init( int intValue ) const
{
    p->SetInt( intValue );
}

void A::Init( const char* stringValue )
{
    p->SetString( stringValue );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Int and String are swapped: you will get a compiler error for const A a; a.Init( "qwerty" );